# How could i write this random number generating button/div syntax in another way?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
// Reference to the <div> which displays the random number:
var rndDiv = document.getElementById('rndNum')

// Reference to the <button> which generates the random number:
var rndBtn = document.getElementById('rnd')

// Generating the random number through 'click' eventlistener:
rndBtn.addEventListener('click', function intRnd() {
  var n = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  console.log(n)
  rndDiv.innerHTML = n
})
```

how could/should i write this code differently, how would you write it? Would you use, for example, arrow functions? let instead of var? I'm just curious. Also i'm the total opposite of a 'pro'-coder, just a beginner, and would like to read your code to this solution.

Thanks for taking your time and reading my post!

Comment: the function intRnd() should be anonymous also could be arrow function without problem.

Comment: Arrow functions are great unless you are worried about compatibility and don't want to bother with something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: In general it is better to use `let` instead of `var`. `var` adds the variable to the window object and could cause a conflict, or just bloat your window unnecessarily. `let` keeps the variable local so it is more tightly scoped. This will allow better garbage collection and reduce other issues.

Comment: This question should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, next time i'll post it there. thank you for all the answers, i learned a lot! so afaiu: anonymous functions are great because you don't have to name them, let is better than var because it has a 'clearer' (more narrow) scope, thus it doesn't clutter things up unnecessary? I'll research further - things like garbage collection and scope/cleaner code in general. const is for variables you know you won't change, am i right there, even slightly?

Comment: There is a lot more to it, but yes you are right.

Comment: thank you! a lot more? i continue learning and researching, through both reading as well as doing (documentation/projects), so what do you specifically mean by a lot more? would be great to hear some examples from your experience!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go ... !

- [IIFE](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/https-medium-com-javascript-in-plain-english-stop-feeling-iffy-about-using-an-iife-7b0292aba174)
- [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Let](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-and-let-in-javascript/)

```js
(function() {
  let rndBtn = document.getElementById('rnd');
  rndBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let rndDiv = document.getElementById('rndNum');
    rndDiv.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  });
})();
```

```html
<button id="rnd">Click</button>
<div id="rndNum"></div>
```

Comment: This is good because it uses `let` instead of `var`, which reduces conflicts in the window object; it wraps everything in an immediately invoked function, which keeps the contents tightly scoped and prevents some types of naming conflicts; and it is using an arrow function, which is just as good as an anonymous function in that the function simply doesn't need a name.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
const randomNumGenerator = () => Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
const randomNumDiv = document.getElementById('rndNum');

document.getElementById('rnd').addEventListener('click', () => {
   randomNumDiv.innerHTML = randomNumGenerator();
});
```